# Why is my Ajax data not sending through to my SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax

I am trying to get my data from a web page to a server without requiring a page refresh. The js brings in the data; however, it (the data) does not reach my db, I am new to ajax and not sure if I am doing this correctly

**JS**:

```
function insert() {
    let batchid = document.getElementById("batchID").value;
    let batchname = document.getElementById("batchName").value;
    let totenum = document.getElementById("toteNum").value;
    let flower = document.getElementById("flowers").value;
    let trim = document.getElementById("trim").value;
    let wastemat = document.getElementById("wasteMaterial").value;
    let empint = document.getElementById("empInital").value;

    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.cshtml?bid=" + batchid + "&bn" + batchname + "&tn" + totenum + "&fl" + flower + "&tr=" + trim + "&wm" + wastemat + "&ei" + empint , false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    alert(" Record inserted successfully");
}
```

**C#**:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Server);

string batchID, batchName, toteNum, flowers, trim, wasteMaterial, empInital;

public void OnGet()
{
    batchID = Request.Query["bid"].ToString();
    batchName = Request.Query["bn"].ToString();
    toteNum = Request.Query["tn"].ToString();
    flowers = Request.Query["fl"].ToString();
    trim = Request.Query["tr"].ToString();
    wasteMaterial = Request.Query["wm"].ToString();
    empInital = Request.Query["ei"].ToString();

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO HarvestedCannabis VALUES ('" + batchID.ToString() + "', '" + batchName.ToString() + "', " +
                                                                    "'" + toteNum.ToString() + "', '" + flowers.ToString() + "', " +
                                                                    "'" + trim.ToString() + "', '" + wasteMaterial.ToString() + "', " +
                                                                    "'" + empInital.ToString() + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

The data is not being added to my db and I am not sure what I'm missing

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Are you able to debug code of `OnGet` method?

Comment: You need to debug your code. Are you request parameters being received correctly? What is the query's command text being set to?

Comment: @marc_s Thank you, I am just doing that for testing i will create an SP after i figure out the ajax portion

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The JS portion goes through with all the data but it does not get to the C# code